# convert word to pdf in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to develope a app like camScaner. In which user can scan any type of file like image, pdf etc and then convert that file from word to pdf. So I want to aske that, is there any way to convert docs file to pdf in react-native?